# gwt-phonegap on android shows blank screen only

Tags: android, gwt, cordova, mgwt

Basic Android application that was created with gwt-phonegap 1.8.1, and compiled on Phonegap Cloud shows only blank white screen. After consulting the site of gwt-phonegap creator following information was found (http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-phonegap-16-issues-with-loading-on.html) However, there is no 'de.kurka.cordova' package in gwt-phonegap 1.8.1 source - so I can not find ways to correct reported error. Can anyone help, please ?

Answer (score 1):

The classes on my my blog are not meant to be used inside your GWT project, they need to be added to your android phonegap project.

Add those classes to your android phonegap project as described in the blog after that your application will start fine.

Comment: Can You, please, elaborate what classes exactly should be added ? Can You show proper project structure ?